# how to remove pagination in datatable

Tags: jquery, html, pagination, datatables

I have used Datatables in grid but need not pagination.

There is a list of orders in one page and I show them in a Datatable grid but in bottom I do not  want to show pagination.
Is there any way to remove or hide pagination from the data table by using a bit customization on the jQuery library.

[image]

I tried to customize it but I found very few methods to do it..

Comment: which method or plugin are you using?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

You should include `"bPaginate": false,` into the configuration object you pass to your constructor parameters. As seen here: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/filter_only.html

Comment: If I want to display only the 100 first lines of my data, bPaginate doesn't work, because it displays all the data regardless of my iDisplayLength parameter. Do you know how to avoid that?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but if you only show the first 100 items and disable pagination, the user has no way to display the following result. If so, then you should try to change you [datasource](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/index.html) directly.
It seems to be a different issue so you should consider opening a new question and give us some of your code.

Comment: Actually, it's for a search function, and I also need to display a message saying the user needs to change her search criteria because too much lines were retrieved. For the record, I asked on the Datatables forum, and the solution is to add an option: sDom = lfrt (without a "p", for no pagination). May be useful...

Answer (score 99):

#### DISABLE PAGINATION

*For DataTables **1.9***

Use [`bPaginate`](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref) option to disable pagination.

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "bPaginate": false
});
```

*For DataTables **1.10+***

Use [`paging`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/paging) option to disable pagination.

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "paging": false
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xft50ho5/232/) for code and demonstration.

#### REMOVE PAGINATION CONTROL AND LEAVE PAGINATION ENABLED

*For DataTables **1.9***

Use [`sDom`](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref) option to configure which control elements appear on the page.

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "sDom": "lfrti"
});
```

*For DataTables **1.10+***

Use [`dom`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option to configure which control elements appear on the page.

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "dom": "lfrti"
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xft50ho5/231/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: for 1.10+, specifiying `data-paging='false'` on the table element will also work.

Answer (score 27):

It's working

Try below code

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sAutoWidth": false,
    "bDestroy":true,
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap", // full_numbers
    "iDisplayStart ": 10,
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "bPaginate": false, //hide pagination
    "bFilter": false, //hide Search bar
    "bInfo": false, // hide showing entries
})
```

Answer (score 21):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Grid_Id').dataTable({
                "bPaginate": false
            });
        });
```

i have solved my problem using it.

Answer (score 17):

```
$('#table_id').dataTable({    
    "bInfo": false, //Dont display info e.g. "Showing 1 to 4 of 4 entries"
    "paging": false,//Dont want paging                
    "bPaginate": false,//Dont want paging      
})
```

Try this code

Answer (score 9):

if you want to remove pagination and but want ordering of dataTable then add this script at the end of your page!

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {        
    $('#table_id').DataTable({
        "paging":   false,
       "info":     false
    } );
      
  } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can add `data-paging='false'` to the `<table>` element and pagination will be disabled for that table.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an alternative that is an incremental improvement on several other answers.  Assuming settings.aLengthMenu is not multi-dimensional (it can be when DataTables has row lengths and labels) and the data will not change after page load (for simple DOM-loaded DataTables), this function can be inserted to eliminate paging.  It hides several paging-related classes.

Perhaps more robust would be setting paging to false inside the function below, however I don't see an API call for that off-hand.

```
$('#myTable').on('init.dt', function(evt, settings) {
    if (settings && settings.aLengthMenu && settings.fnRecordsTotal && settings.fnRecordsTotal() < settings.aLengthMenu[0]) {
        // hide pagination controls, fewer records than minimum length
        $(settings.nTableWrapper).find('.dataTables_paginate, .dataTables_length, .dataTables_info').hide();
    }
}).DataTable();
```