# jQuery Datatables - Disable pagination and search if no results?

Tags: jquery, datatable, pagination

My AJAX call gets JSON data which can sometimes be empty. If I set the `paginate` option to true, the search and pagination components are shown even if I have 0 results. In which case I set the data to an empty object as `[{}]`. My settings are as follows:

```
processing: true,
serverSide: true,
autoWidth: false,
ordering: false,
searching:true,
lengthChange:false,
info: false
```

The JSON as follows:

```
draw: 1
length: 10
recordsFiltered: 10
recordsTotal: 1
start: 0
data: [..... list of items]
```

How to disable these two components if I have no data?

Update: I am not trying to change a setting after render, I am simply not able to understand why is Datatable showing pagination if the results are 0 and is there a way to avoid it. Currently I have hidden it using the `xhr` event to check the length of the data.

Comment: @SinanSamet Yes, I have seen that answer already, read my update please. I am NOT TRYING TO CHANGE A SETTING!

Comment: Ah okay, taking that into account it seems like this would be the best solution possible for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38853805/1421775. Does that one help?

Comment: Perfect, that seems a bit more neat than what I am doing. I check the length of the data in the `xhr` event and hide the pagination and search DOM elements using jQuery. You can add that as an answer, I will accept it. However I wonder how a library like this doesn't handle this on its own.

Comment: Yes, it's been there for ages I would expect that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38853805/1421775) answer you have to use the drawCallback option to find out how many pages exist. You can then hide the pagination when the pages are equal to 1.

> BitOfUniverse:
>
> Use drawCallback option to handle DT draw event and show/hide
>   pagination control based on available pages:
>
> ```
> $('#table_id').dataTable({
>   drawCallback: function(settings) {
>     var pagination = $(this).closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.dataTables_paginate');
>     pagination.toggle(this.api().page.info().pages > 1);
>   }
> })
> ```