# Jquery DataTable remove pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, datatables

I have a little problem . I want to **remove auto pagination** from my datatable. I have tried many way to remove it.

```
$('#dataTable').DataTable({
            "paging": false  or "bPaginate": false
});
```

> in both cases it doesn't remove pagination :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832742/how-to-remove-pagination-in-datatable

Comment: for datatable verison 1.10 and above [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/2557/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This how I remove everything from the bottom:

```
$("#dataTable").DataTable( {
    "bInfo" : false,
    "paging": false,
    "ordering": false,
    "searching": false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#dataTable').DataTable( {
        "paging":   false,
        "ordering": false,
        "info":     false
    });
```

or https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/filter_only.html

Comment: could tell you in detail if you will post your complete code.

Comment: Ohh sorry guys , I have solved this problem with clearing my browser cache(hitting ctrl+f5).