# Hide Pagination in Datatable not Remove

Tags: datatable, pagination

I have this script that works but it totally removes the pagination and display all the data, what I need is just to hide the pagination. any idea ?

I tried this but this is a different approach
[how to remove pagination in datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832742/how-to-remove-pagination-in-datatable)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "paging":   false,
        "ordering": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "info":     false
    });
} );
</script>
```

Comment: try the `dom` attribute for the DataTable, just don't include it when you're doing it https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

Comment: or `$('.dataTables_paginate').hide()` ...

Answer (score 1):

Set `"bPaginate"` to `false` in the datatable configuration.

Try this code:

```js
$('#table_id').dataTable({    
    "bInfo": false,
    "paging": false,             
    "bPaginate": false,   
})
```